# Convert string to devnagari unicode

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to get the `Devnagari Unicode` of a given string.

https://codepoints.net/U+0924

I have string = "**त**"

How do I get its Unicode value (\u0924)?

I would like to get it in `php` or `javascript`.

**Update**

Also, string = "**tkfO{**". This should return `\u0924\u092A\u093E\u0908`.

1. https://codepoints.net/U+0924
2. https://codepoints.net/U+092A
3. https://codepoints.net/U+093E
4. https://codepoints.net/U+0908

Comment: What is “ tkfO{”?!

Comment: Please check my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `mb_ord` and than `dechex`

```
print dechex(mb_ord("त"));
```

Comment: Note that it requires PHP 7.2. You should also specify the encoding as 2nd parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way in PHP:

```
function encodeString($str)
{
    $s = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-32BE', $str);
    $nb = strlen($s) / 4;
    $res = '';
    for($i=0;$i<$nb;$i++)
        $res .= encodeChar(substr($s, 4*$i, 4));
    return $res;
}

function encodeChar($c)
{
    $s = bin2hex($c);
    while(substr($s,0,2)=='00')
        $s = substr($s, 2);
    return '\\u'.$s;
}

echo encodeString('तपाई');
```

Output: `\u0924\u092a\u093e\u0908`